# ihasapp to get list of installed apps on ios giving an error

Tags: ios, sigabrt

i found the ihasapp framework on github: https://github.com/danielamitay/iHasApp

i included the two files into the project..however it is giving an error:

> 2013-03-14 11:21:35.848 apps[4338:2203] *** Terminating app due to
>   uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '***
>   -[NSConcreteData initWithContentsOfFile:options:error:]: nil file argument'

here's the code that i am using in my viewcontroller:

```
#import "helloworldViewController.h"
#import "iHasApp.h"

@interface helloworldViewController ()

@end

@implementation helloworldViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    iHasApp *detectionObject = [iHasApp new];
    [detectionObject detectAppDictionariesWithIncremental:^(NSArray *appDictionaries) {
        NSLog(@"Incremental appDictionaries.count: %i", appDictionaries.count);
    } withSuccess:^(NSArray *appDictionaries) {
        NSLog(@"Successful appDictionaries.count: %i", appDictionaries.count);
    } withFailure:^(NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Failure: %@", error.localizedDescription);
    }];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

i am really new to ios development so the error might be very minor/silly. but any help would be great!

Answer (score 1):

Author here:

`iHasApp` was asking for the filepath of a resource item internally, which was returning `nil`. It then made an `NSData` request using the `nil` argument.

Fix pushed to GitHub.

Comment: hi, thanks. i did not get the chance to try this out again. will do so soon and let u know if it worked! :)

Comment: hi @Daniel Amitay i am getting this error "SIGABRT  __63-[iHasApp detectAppIdsWithIncremental:withSuccess:withFailure:]_block_invoke_3 (iHasApp.m:45)" I have posted issue on github please help me to find the problem